# WPF Display Design Data instead of a DataTable returned by method

Tags: c#, xaml, datatable, datagrid, sample-data

I need help in displaying sample data. Currently I have a DataTable that is provided as input in the window constructor. My setup is the following:

The window class

```
public partial class Project_Status_Window : Window {

    //Required for the datacontext
    public DataTable status { get; }


    public Project_Status_Window(DataTable status) {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.status = status;
        this.Show();
    }
}//End of Window Class
```

This is a fairly simple class. The status property is set in the constructor. In the formatting side of things I want the new window that is created to display **some** of the columns of the DataTable and format other columns based on values of columns that are not displayed. In my XAML I declare a DataGrid as follows:

```
     <DataGrid x:Name="Status_Table_Viewer"
                      DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding status.DefaultView}" Grid.Row="0"
                      SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="Cell" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Order_Number}"  Header="Order Number"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Order_Line}" Header="Order Line"/>
                    <!-- More Columns and formating that is irrelevant -->
                </DataGrid.Columns>
     </DataGrid>
```

However further this setup is time consuming for me to develop. I have found some articles in order to display data but those do not seem to apply in my case.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to be able to use the designer inside visual studio with sample data loaded in the design tab.